# Address of static variable changes between static inline function calls

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm not great at C (I'm an iOS developer) so this one's confusing me:

I've got a header file where I define some localisation helpers:

```
#ifndef LocalizationMacros_h
#define LocalizationMacros_h

static NSString * forcedLanguage = nil;

static inline void forceLanguage(NSString*language){
    NSLog(@"Forcing language %@ (%i)", language, &forcedLanguage);
    // Output: Forcing language de (5248160)

    forcedLanguage = language;
}

static inline NSString * translate(NSString * language, NSString * key){
    NSLog(@"Forced language: %@ (%i)", forcedLanguage, &forcedLanguage);
    // Output: Forced language: (null) (5248236)

    // ... do some stuff to put translation into result ...
    return result;
}

#endif
```

I don't understand why the address of `forcedLanguage` changes between `forceLanguage()` and `translate()`, resulting in `(null)` as its value. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: I'm guessing that `inline` causes a separate static to be created local to each compilation unit.  Are your two methods in different compilation units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` keyword localises the object to the translation unit in which it is placed - you have placed it in a header file, so it can be included in multiple translation units.

Here `static` is being used as a linkage modifier; in this context it is not a storage class specifier - all data declared outside of a function will have static storage class in any case.  What you want here is to make it global (a matter of fact rather than recommendation) - i.e. to give it `extern` linkage.  External linkage is the default whether you declare it `extern` or not.

If you give it external linkage, then the header must contain only a declaration, not an instantiation - the instantiation must be in a single translation unit.

Comment: Do you mean 'compilation unit' (as opposed to 'translation unit')? I think I'll accept this answer even though both are good, because it explains the whys a bit more.

Comment: compilation unit/translation unit - they are the same thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)

Answer (score 4):

You are defining a copy of the `forcedLanguage` variable for every source file that includes your header. In your header change:

```
static NSString * forcedLanguage = nil;
```

to:

```
extern NSString * forcedLanguage;
```

and then in one source file (ideally the one that corresponds with your header) define:

```
NSString * forcedLanguage = nil;
```

For future reference, the rule of thumb is: variable *declarations* go in header files, variable *definitions* go in source files.